# Why inner div container overflows?

Tags: html, css

From below code,

```css
.shoppingform {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  background: #7CB9E8;
  /* url(some img)*/
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.customercardtype {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 2px 5px 5px;
  background: #B284BE;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 8%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.customercardtype .formlabel {
  display: block;
  height: 20%
}
.customercardtype .cardtypecontainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; /* Any problem here? */
  top: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form class="shoppingform" action="someaction.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Step3: Card details
  <div class="customercardtype">
    <label class="formlabel">Cardtype:</label>
    <div class="cardtypecontainer">

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I would like to understand,

Why inner `div` container overflows?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the width of an element is actually width + left padding + right padding + left border + right border.

As your width is 100% and additional to this will push it over 100%, making it overflow its parent.

If you use box-sizing: border-box, that will fix this issue.

That's a quick summary, lots more in depth info here: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it overflows is because [position absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) visually speaking, positions your element outside the normal flow of the site. This is intentional and powerful if you use it correctly. However in your case, the parent container of `cardtypecontainer` was not taking control of the absolute positioned element, therefore it overflowed outside its container.

Then, I changed `cardtypecontainer` to have `relative` position, which will work as you intended it to, because `relative` position does not change the intended layout of the element. For your case it means, `cardtypecontainer` will stay within the bounds of its parent container.

```css
.shoppingform {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  background: #7CB9E8;
  /* url(some img)*/
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.customercardtype {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 2px 5px 5px;
  background: #B284BE;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 8%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.customercardtype .formlabel {
  display: block;
  height: 20%
}
.customercardtype .cardtypecontainer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form class="shoppingform" action="someaction.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Step3: Card details
  <div class="customercardtype">
    <label class="formlabel">Cardtype:</label>
    <div class="cardtypecontainer">

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```